# Pgfplots center plot horizontally, disregarding legend

Tags: pgfplots

I tried a lot around with setting anchors in the plot, but I couldn't manage to center the plot correctly.

In this example the bounding box of plot and legend gets centered, but I want the plot centered, ignoring the legend.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
  \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[legend pos=outer north east]
      \addplot [domain=0:pi] {sin(deg(x))};
      \addplot [domain=0:pi] {sin(deg(x))};
      \legend{longlonglongplotname, plotname}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis right,trim axis left]`?

Comment: Ah, applying it to the `tikzpicture` environment did the trick. I tried only to add it to the `axis`

Comment: Makes a difference when I tested here. Note this applies to the `tikzpicture` environment, not the `axis`.

Comment: You're welcome. I see a question that is essentially the same, and with the same answer, was posted earlier, so I will vote to close this a duplicate.